# Symbol for "care of" (c/o)

Tags: symbols

Is there a c/o symbol in LaTex for writing an address? I have looked in the [Comprehensive latex symbol list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) but couldn't find one.

Comment: I do not think there is such a symbol, doesn people just write `c/o`?

Comment: [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) doesn't know it :-(

Comment: It’s in unicode, however: ℅

Comment: Maybe something like this could be a reasonable substitute: `\usepackage{amsmath,relsize,units}\def\careof{\smaller\nicefrac{\text{c}}{\text{o}}}`?

Comment: @daleif: Actually, when you write 'c/o' in any word processor (MS Word, OpenOffice, Google Docs) it is typeset beautifully, that's why I thought there might be a symbol for that in LaTeX too.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for checking anyway :) @Kahen: I will try that and come back, thanks.

Comment: On page 67 of the symbols list it says: nicefrac (part of the units package) or the newer xfrac package can be used to
construct vulgar fractions like \1/2", \1/4", \3/4", and even \c/o" (like @kahens solution I guess)

Comment: @kushal: Note that only the first user mentioned with `@` in a comment is notified.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably quick and dirty, see [ISO character entities and their LaTeX equivalents](http://www.bitjungle.com/isoent/index_files/isoent-ref.pdf) on page 3:

```
${^c\!/\!_o}$ Jim Jones
```

[image: symbol “care of” (c/o) with LaTeX]

---

Edit: Included suggestion from Tobi’s comment having the letters `c` and `o` non-italicised:

```
$\mathrm{^c\!/\!_o}$ Jim Jones
```

[image: symbol “care of” (c/o) with LaTeX]

Comment: Very dirty ;-) I’d at least add `\mathrm` to make c and o non-italic …

Answer (score 24):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\newcommand{\co}{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
  \setbox 2 = \hbox {\small c}%
  \setbox 0 = \hbox {/}%
  \dimen 0 = \ht 0  \advance \dimen 0 by -\ht 2
  \raise \dimen 0 \box 2
  \kern -0.3333\wd0/\kern -0.3333\wd 0
  \lower \dp 0 \hbox {\small o}%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\co\space Mr. Bean
\end{document}
```

[image: output result]

Answer (score 14):

The "c" should be level with ascenders and the "o" at the baseline; with `textcomp`'s `\textfractionsolidus` the slash is slightly better than the normal `/`; but for symmetry it can be slightly raised up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\co}{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \raisebox{.85ex}{\fontsize{\sf@size}{\z@}\selectfont c}%
  \kern-.1em\raisebox{.2ex}{\textfractionsolidus}\kern-.1em
  {\fontsize{\sf@size}{\z@}\selectfont o}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\co\ Mr.~Bean

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for whatever it's worth, the image for the unicode symbol (U+2105) shows the letters in italic.

Comment: @barbarabeeton If that's preferred, just change `\selectfont` into `\itshape`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. This `\co` macro is nearly the same that a macro used by LyX to obtain the c/o symbol (`\LyXcareof`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\co{\mbox{%
\raisebox{.8ex}{c}%
\kern-.175em\raisebox{.2ex}{/}%
\kern-.18em\raisebox{-.2ex}{o}%
}~}

\begin{document}
  \co Mr. Bean
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With XeLaTeX and a font that can display the character you can use the [unicode character U+2105](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%84%85#English) and write `\char"2105`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% load a font that can display the symbol
\usepackage{noto}

\begin{document}
  \char"2105
  \symbol{"2105} % alternative syntax, see comment below.
  ^^^^2105 % yet another syntax
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with pdfLaTeX and probably not with others as well.

Comment: Of course, the glyph U+2105 is provided by the font. The LaTeX syntax for plain TeX's `\char"2105` is `\symbol{"2105}`. Alternatively, the [^^-notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62725/16967) can be used: `^^^^2105`.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the answer accordingly. Still, I could not get it to work with LaTeX or pdfLaTeX (not sure what's the real problem though).

Answer (score 1):

I've got a better one.

[image: care of]

```
\usepackage{units}
…
{\nicefrac{\raisebox{.2em}{\textsc{c}}}{\raisebox{-.3em}{\textsc{\kern -.1em o}}}}
```