# Why does \def@#1\space not work?

Tags: macros, active-characters

The code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\catcode`@\active
\def@#1\par{<#1>}

@some text


\endgroup
\end{document}
```

works flawlessly. Why not so when I replace it by the following?

```
\def@#1\space{<#1>}
```

Comment: `\par` appears when TeX tokenizes the end of lines (so the definition of `@` actually *finds* the `\par` token because TeX inserts it). `\space` is a macro, but it doesn't appear “magically” like `\par`. You can use `\def@#1 {<#1>}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\def@#1\space{<#1>}` doesn't work, unless TeX finds the token `\space` before the current paragraph ends.

Recall that TeX doesn't do expansion when

1. absorbing the parameter text of a macro
2. looking for arguments to a macro

On the other hand,

```
\def@#1 {<#1>}
```

will work. Here's a Plain TeX example (so I'll use `\tt`):

```
\begingroup
\catcode`@\active
\def@#1 {{\tt<#1>}}

@some text

@some

\endgroup

\bye
```

[image]

However, you probably want to delimit the argument with the end-of-line. See [Using end-of-line delimiter in plain Tex macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125549/using-end-of-line-delimiter-in-plain-tex-macro) for this case.

There is a fundamental difference between `\par` and `\space`. The former is a primitive (unless redefined); TeX inserts automatically a `\par` token when it sees a category code 5 character when in state *S* (start of line), during the tokenization process. So

```
\def\foo#1\par{Something with #1}
```

and the call

```
\foo xyz

something else after a blank line
```

will correctly identify `xyz` (with a trailing space, though) as the argument to `\foo`.

The *macro* `\space` is defined by `\def\space{ }`, and there's no magic process that automatically inserts such a token.