# Trailing space in parameter delimited with \par

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I just realized that when I use `\par` as a macro parameter delimiter the parameter then contains a trailing space.

MWE:

```
\def\test #1\par{\def\param{#1}}
\test test

\hbox{\vrule\param\vrule}     % prints "|test |"

\bye
```

Is it a bug or standard behaviour, and if the latter, why is it so? Thx.

**In reply to wipet's answer**
@wipet: Thx, but I need more complex solution and I am not sure I would be able to adapt your suggestion for that.

Here is what I am doing. I have a file with a lot of macros, among others those to define and to place pictures and their descriptions, looking as follows.

```
% picture definition
% #1 - reference name (must be unique within a book or article, not necessarily within a volume or entire collection)
% #2 - base file name (without suffix)
% #3 - picture title
\def\picdef #1 #2 #3\par{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname picfile-#1\endcsname\relax\else
        \errmessage{Picture definition duplicity: reference #1 already defined!}\fi
    \expandafter\def\csname picfile-#1\endcsname{\localPath/imgs/#2}%
    \expandafter\def\csname pictitle-#1\endcsname{#3\unskip}%
}


% picture description definition
% #1 - reference name
% #2 - picture description
\long\def\picdesc #1 #2\descend{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname picfile-#1\endcsname\relax
        \errmessage{Define picture first before defining its description}%
    \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\long\expandafter\def\csname picdesc-#1\endcsname{#2\unskip}%
    \fi
}


% user macros to actually place the picture or its description
\def\obrazek #1 {%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname picfile-#1\endcsname\relax
        \message{Warning: unknown picture reference #1 (typo or not yet defined?)!}%
    \else
        \ifhmode\par\fi
        \begin{figure}[t]
            \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{\csname picfile-#1\endcsname}}
            \vskip 14pt
            \centerline{\large \bfseries {\csname pictitle-#1\endcsname}}
        \end{figure}
    \fi
}


\def\obrazekPopis #1 {%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname picfile-#1\endcsname\relax
        \message{Warning: unknown picture reference #1 (typo or not yet defined?)!}%
    \else
        \ifhmode\par\fi
        \csname pictitle-#1\endcsname: \csname picdesc-#1\endcsname\par
    \fi
}
```

Then for a particular work within a volume there is a file with picture definitions like this:

```
\picdef
    logo-s              % small logo
    logo_min            % logo_min.pdf
    Obr. 1              % Czech for Pic. 1

\picdesc logo-s
    This is what a~small logo is supposed to look like.
\descend

\endinput
```

And finally within an actual text pictures are placed like this:

```
Some text
and text

\obrazek logo-s

Some other text
etc.

\obrazekPopis logo-s

And text continues on
```

Comment: Related: [Using end-of-line delimiter in plain Tex macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125549)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is that way just because that's the way it is. Essentially the first end of line turns into a space as usual, the second newline turns into `\par`. The normal `\par` behaviour does an `\unskip` to remove a final glue node (usually from this space) before breaking the lines..

A couple of possibilities below.

```
\def\test #1\par{\def\param{#1}}
\test test

\hbox{\vrule\param\vrule}     % prints "|test |"

\def\testB #1 \par{\def\param{#1}}
\testB test

\hbox{\vrule\param\vrule}     % prints "|test|"

\def\testC #1\par{\def\param{#1\unskip}}
\testC test

\hbox{\vrule\param\vrule}     % prints "|test|"

\bye
```

Note that if you use an actual explicit `\par` in the use as in

```
\test test\par
```

then the additional space is not there, so your original would not have an extra space. `\testB` would have an error as it would be looking for a `\par` preceded by a space.

Comment: It is not good idea to use the variant of type `\testB` in general because the usage `\testB about \TeX` (end line), (empty line) causes an error.

Comment: @David: Thx. So the testC seems to be the correct solution as it works correctly both with and without explicit `\par` delimiter and also it follows the way TeX does it internally. Does it have any drawbacks I am overlooking?

Comment: @wipet yes as I note above. (well I noted a slightly different case but anyway)

Comment: @MarcelS. not necessarily, the `\unskip` removes the space if you are just typesetting the saved paragraph text but if, for example you are writing it to a file, or parsing a special file format such as a comma separate value line,  it will write as `\unskip` which may not be what you want, in which case you need to do a second pass and explicitly test for and remove a trailing space token before saving the text.

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility. To create a macro, which reads its parameter to the end of line. This solution is inspired from OPmac trick 0121. Macro programmer can use

```
\eoldef\macro#1{here is a parameter "#1"}
```

and then `\macro text<end of line>` causes that "#1" is `text`. The `\eoldef` macro can be defined by:

```
\gdef\eoldef#1{\def#1{\begingroup \catcode`\^^M=12 \eoldefA#1}%
   \expandafter\def\csname\string#1:G\endcsname}
{\catcode`\^^M=12 %
 \gdef\eoldefA#1#2^^M{\endgroup\csname\string#1:G\endcsname{#2}}}
```

Comment: See my own “answer” (not real one, but I cannot place proper formatting in a comment and also it is too long for a comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{u{\par}}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \param { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test test

\mbox{\vrule\param\vrule}     % prints "|test|"

\end{document}
```

It can be done also with plain TeX, of course, but only for `pdftex`.

[image]

You can also get your more complicated macros with just some more work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% first and second argument delimited by spaces
\NewDocumentCommand{\picdef}{u{~}u{~}u{\par}}
 {
  \marcels_pic_def:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\picdesc}{u{~}u{\par}}
 {
  \marcels_pic_desc:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\obrazek}{u{~}}
 {
  \marcels_pic_obrazek:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\obrazekPopis}{u{~}}
 {
  \marcels_pic_popis:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_marcels_pic_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_def:nnn
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { marcels/pic } { duplicate } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \__marcels_pic_defnew:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcels_pic_defnew:nnn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { image } { \LocalPath/imgs/#2 }
  \prop_gput:cnx { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { title } { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #3 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_desc:nn
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { desc } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { marcels/pic } { early } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_obrazek:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \__marcels_pic_obrazek_out:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { marcels/pic } { undefined } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcels_pic_obrazek_out:n
 {
  \par
  \begin{figure}[tp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]
   {
    \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { image }
   }
  \par\vspace{14pt}
  {\large\bfseries \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { title }}
  \end{figure}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_popis:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \__marcels_pic_popis_out:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { marcels/pic } { undefined } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcels_pic_popis_out:n
 {
  \par
  \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { title }:~
  \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { desc }
  \par
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { marcels/pic } { duplicate }
 {
  Picture~name~'#1'~defined
 }
 {
  The~name~'#1'~is~already~assigned;~I'll~ignore~the~new~definition
 }

\msg_new:nnn { marcels/pic } { early }
 {
  Description~before~definition~of~'#1'
 }

\msg_new:nnn { marcels/pic } { undefined }
 {
  Undefined~picture~'#1'
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\picdef
    logo-s              % small logo
    logo_min            % logo_min.pdf
    Obr. 1              % Czech for Pic. 1

\picdesc logo-s
    This is what a~small logo is supposed to look like.

Some text
and text

\obrazek logo-s

Some other text
etc.

\obrazekPopis logo-s

And text continues on

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with the same output. A key-value interface is, in my opinion, much clearer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\picdef}{mm}
 {%#1 = name, #2 = key-value pairs
  \marcels_pic_def:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\obrazek}{m}
 {
  \marcels_pic_obrazek:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\obrazekPopis}{m}
 {
  \marcels_pic_popis:n { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { marcels/pic }
 {
  image .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l_marcels_pic_tmp_prop { image } { \LocalPath/imgs/#1 },
  title .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l_marcels_pic_tmp_prop { title } { #1 },
  desc  .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l_marcels_pic_tmp_prop { desc } { #1 },
 }

\seq_new:N \g_marcels_pic_list_seq
\prop_new:N \l_marcels_pic_tmp_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_def:nn
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { marcels/pic } { duplicate } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \__marcels_pic_defnew:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcels_pic_defnew:nn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
  \prop_clear:N \l_marcels_pic_tmp_prop
  \keys_set:nn { marcels/pic } { #2 }
  \prop_new:c { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_eq:cN { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } \l_marcels_pic_tmp_prop
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_desc:nn
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { desc } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { marcels/pic } { early } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_obrazek:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \__marcels_pic_obrazek_out:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { marcels/pic } { undefined } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcels_pic_obrazek_out:n
 {
  \par
  \begin{figure}[tp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]
   {
    \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { image }
   }
  \par\vspace{14pt}
  {\large\bfseries \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { title }}
  \end{figure}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcels_pic_popis:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_marcels_pic_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \__marcels_pic_popis_out:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { marcels/pic } { undefined } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcels_pic_popis_out:n
 {
  \par
  \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { title }:~
  \prop_item:cn { g_marcels_pic_#1_prop } { desc }
  \par
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { marcels/pic } { duplicate }
 {
  Picture~name~'#1'~defined
 }
 {
  The~name~'#1'~is~already~assigned;~I'll~ignore~the~new~definition
 }

\msg_new:nnn { marcels/pic } { early }
 {
  Description~before~definition~of~'#1'
 }

\msg_new:nnn { marcels/pic } { undefined }
 {
  Undefined~picture~'#1'
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\picdef{logo-s} % small logo
 {
  image=logo_min, % logo_min.pdf
  title=Obr. 1,   % Czech for Pic. 1
  desc=This is what a~small logo is supposed to look like.
 }

Some text
and text

\obrazek{logo-s}

Some other text
etc.

\obrazekPopis{logo-s}

And text continues on

\end{document}
```