# List item with math environment?

Tags: math-mode, lists

I am currently working on a very math-heavy document with a lot of lists. Is it possible to define an `\item` that automatically puts its content in math mode to avoid having to write `\item $ $` all the time? I imagine something like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \mathitem some math
    \item some text
\end{itemize}
```

I know you can make a math version of the entire itemize environment, but that does not really help since there are many lists with both math and text entries.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This can undoubtedly be done, but since `\item` is only started, not ended, the text would probably be best entered between braces -- `\mathitem{...}` -- which isn't really an improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution could be useful for you. But you have to avoid (at least) two things:

1. avoid empty arguments of `\mathitem`,
2. the content of `\mathitem` must be placed within one line (in fact, the end of the line is the argument separator of `\mathitem`).

[image]

Here is the code...

```
\documentclass{article}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125549/using-end-of-line-delimiter-in-plain-tex-macro
% (OPmac-solution)
% ------------------
\def\eoldef#1{%
    \def#1{\begingroup \catcode`\^^M=12 \eoldefA#1}%
        \expandafter\def\csname\string#1:M\endcsname}
{\catcode`\^^M=12
    \gdef\eoldefA#1#2^^M{\endgroup\csname\string#1:M\endcsname{#2}}}

% definition of \mathitem (avoid empty arguments)
\eoldef\mathitem #1{%
    \item $#1$}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \mathitem 4x^2\cdot\sinh (x)
  \item third one
  \mathitem \zeta ^\star (2,1)=2\zeta (3)
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although paragraph breaks are not permitted within a math environment, I can envision such an item that should be more than one "paragraph".  I guess it could be handled as `\mathitem ...$\endgraf$...`

Comment: Dearest Marian, always thank you for your attention to me. +1