# Shortcut without braces for begin{itemize} - item - end{itemize}

Tags: itemize, shortcut

I am using LaTeX inside a graphical editor (IPE) for presentations and would like to speed up creating itemize environments, as I use them very frequently.
I have different text fields for each item and they all get compiled individually by the editor, so I basically need to re-create the itemize environment for every text field.
This is what I currently use:

```
\newcommand{\e}[1]{\begin{itemize}\item #1\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ee}[1]{\begin{itemize}\begin{itemize}\item #1\end{itemize}\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\eee}[1]{\begin{itemize}\begin{itemize}\begin{itemize}\item #1\end{itemize}\end{itemize}\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\w}[2][1.]{\begin{enumerate}\item[#1] #2\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\ww}[2][(a)]{\begin{enumerate}\begin{enumerate}\item[#1] #2\end{enumerate}\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\www}[2][i.]{\begin{enumerate}\begin{enumerate}\begin{enumerate}\item[#1] #2\end{enumerate}\end{enumerate}\end{enumerate}}
```

This way I can simply use `\e{some text}` and `\ee{more text}` for individual levels of itemize (and enumerate).

Now the question: I'd rather like to use `\e some text` and `\ee more text` as this is much simpler to handle. Especially when editing stuff I often have to de-select the braces in order to not overwrite them. But LaTeX only takes  a single token as argument when you omit the braces, so I get an annoying line break after the first character.

I could think of multiple solutions:

- Is it possible to tell LaTeX to use the entire remainder of the line as #1 argument?
- Is it possible to replicate the behavior of itemize (the symbol of \item, the font size of the three layers, the indentation especially after a line break) without the environment?
- Is it possible to prevent the line break after `\end{itemize}` and just continue typing on your `\item`? This should however still result in correct indentation after a natural line break occurs.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Willie Wong  provided me with [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125549/using-end-of-line-delimiter-in-plain-tex-macro) that did the trick for itemize. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Such shortness on the first sight seems to make code shorter, less time consuming at writing and even easy to understand etc. However, after a while you will recognize that this not a case. Even worse, no one except you will understand what the code means. I would discourage you to do this.,

Comment: The very first "solution" is possible; instead of using `\newcommand` it is _possible_ to use `\def` with the end of line as one of the delimiters of input. Doing so is [however slightly tricky](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125549/using-end-of-line-delimiter-in-plain-tex-macro), and probably for other reasons not a great idea.

Comment: Your second and third solutions would make the syntax a lot less like TeX and a lot more like troff. (Unfortunately given your preambled it appears you are constrained to use TeX.)

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for the link, that did the trick for itemize. I left enumerate as it is, since I am rarely using it and it relies on an optional argument. Whatever the reasons for not using it may be, it probably does not matter in my situation - I just won't do anything fancy inside my macro. :) I am not producing entire documents with it, but I am separately typesetting individual pieces of text inside a GUI editor. If you'd like to post it as an actual answer, I could mark it as the solution.