# How to type Unicode in plain TeX

Tags: unicode, plain-tex

In plain TeX,

```
\char<int>
```

produces character with decimal code <*int*>.
Similarly,

```
\char'<oct>
\char"<hex>
```

produce character with octal code<*oct*>, and hexadecimal code <*hex*> respectively.

Is there such a way of typing Unicode symbols ?

Thank you.

Comment: In (Xe|Lua)TeX just `\char"<hex>` works, or may be the expandable `\Uchar"<hex>`.

Comment: You need an unicode aware engine to do it; macro packages like Plain cannot do it by themselves.

Answer (score 9):

You can somewhat emulate Unicode also with Plain TeX; say you want to input `ć` and get `\'c` out of it.

```
\catcode"C4=\active % 0xC4 is a two-byte prefix in UTF-8
\def^^c4#1{\csname\string^^c4#1\endcsname}

\expandafter\def\csname\string^^c4^^87\endcsname{\'c}
%%% add other UTF-8 characters having 0xC4 as prefix

%%% Repeat for all other UTF-8 prefixes you need

ć

\bye
```

Repeat for all prefixes.

You may want to look at http://petr.olsak.net/csplain-e.html for a different strategy and an already baked solution.

Comment: doesn't csplain depend on the encTeX extension, as I already pointed out?

Comment: @TarsTarkas Yes, that's why I said it uses a different strategy.

Comment: In any event, activating characters or transforming input is a whole different game than using the `\char` primitive, isn't it?

Comment: With TeX you can't use `\char<number>` with a number beyond 255, can you? You have to switch to XeTeX or LuaTeX for this, with *many* problems, of course.

Comment: I know... but your proposed solution assumes the OP is using an 8bit TeX _engine_, and afaik, they can't activate single tokens over the 7bit range with XeTeX or LuaTeX. afaics, the OP is only assuming the use of the Plain TeX _macros_, so they can use Plain TeX with the XeTeX or LuaTeX _engine_.

Comment: @TarsTarkas No tag [tag:xetex] or [tag:luatex] is accompanying the question. With XeTeX you can certainly type `\char"1234`, but no output would result, unless you set up an OpenType/TrueType font.

Comment: the OP is asking about how to use the primitive `\char` to input unicode characters, so the answer should be: you can't do that with an 8bit font or engine, but you can with a unicode aware font _and_ engine.

Comment: How can I find the associated number for an arbitrary character say "ı" for example and what is the meaning of double caret `^^`?

Comment: @Vesnog For `^^` see [What is the role of an unescaped circumflex or hat character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253469/). For finding the UTF-8 representation you can use http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

Answer (score 3):

You need an unicode aware engine to do it; macro packages like Plain cannot do it by themselves. Examples of unicode aware engines are xetex and luatex, and perhaps etex and pdftex with the enctex extension.