# The "^'' glyph in the TeXBook

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, primitives, knuth, texbook.tex

TeX, plain TeX, within the source of the Texbook of Don Knuth, there is use of ^ in different command sequences, and  in text bites.

Is there a special meaning to `^` in TeX primitives, in plain TeX, is it a part of a macro defined in Knuth's proprietary input files to the TeXbook?

The output seems not to betray the intended use.

Comment: Those files are not proprietary if I'm not mistaken. Are you referring to, e.g., `^^{TeX78}` and `^^|\copyright|`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 19):

The `manmac` format used for processing the TeXbook defines `^` in a very special way.

Under the standard setup, `^` alone is the marker for superscripts and also has a very peculiar behavior when followed by itself, see [What is the role of an unescaped circumflex or hat character " ^ "?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253469/what-is-the-role-of-an-unescaped-circumflex-or-hat-character)

However, `manmac.tex` makes `^` into an active character and Knuth uses it for indexing:

```
% Indexing macros
\newif\ifproofmode
\proofmodetrue % this should be false when making camera-ready copy
\newwrite\inx
\immediate\openout\inx=index % file for index reminders
\newif\ifsilent
\def\specialhat{\ifmmode\def\next{^}\else\let\next=\beginxref\fi\next}
\def\beginxref{\futurelet\next\beginxrefswitch}
\def\beginxrefswitch{\ifx\next\specialhat\let\next=\silentxref
  \else\silentfalse\let\next=\xref\fi \next}
\catcode`\^=\active \let ^=\specialhat
\def\silentxref^{\silenttrue\xref}
```

Let's look at some calls from the source of the TeXbook.

```
Another noteworthy characteristic of this manual is that it doesn't
always tell the ^{truth}.

Let's keep the name \TeX\
for the language described here, since it is so much better, and since
it is not going to change any more. ^^{TeX78}

medium that doesn't allow lowering of the `E', is to type `^|TeX|'. Then

The solution is to type \thinspace|'\thinspace''|, which
produces '\thinspace'' as desired.^^|\thinspace|
```

Snippet 1 has a word that is both indexed and printed; snippet 2 has a word that is indexed but not printed. Snippets 3 and 4 are similar, but the term is stored verbatim in the index auxiliary file.

Note that in the TeXbook, `|...|` is always used as a shorthand for printing a term verbatim.

The character `^` is made active and its meaning is made identical to `\specialhat`.

If the character is found in math mode, a standard category code `^` is delivered to the main input stream, thus enabling usage of superscripts with the standard notation.

In text mode it is different, because `\beginxref` is delivered.

The `\beginxref` macro checks the next token with `\futurelet`. If the next token is `^`, `\silentxref` is delivered, otherwise `\ifsilent` is set to false and `\xref` is delivered.

As you see, `\silentxref` gobbles the next `^` and does `\silenttrue\xref`.

Describing `\xref` would be very long and not relevant to the description you were looking for.

A subtle point to be noted. The `^` in the replacement text for `\specialhat` appears *before* the change in category code, so it is the normal “superscript” character (tokens in the replacement text are “frozen” at definition time). The `^` in the parameter text of `\silentxref` appears after the category code change, so it should have category code 13 when `\silentxref` is expanded (which is normally already ensured by the fact that `\silentxref` has been called).

---

Just to play around, here's an `expl3` version of the code (just the macros, not the setup for writing to the auxiliary index file)

```
\bool_new:N \l_manmac_silent_bool
\cs_new_protected:Nn \manmac_specialhat:
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF { ^ } { \manmac_beginxref: }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \manmac_beginxref:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF ^
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l_manmac_silent_bool \manmac_xref:
   }
   {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_manmac_silent_bool \manmac_xref:
   }
 }
\char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \manmac_specialhat:
\char_set_catcode_active:N ^
```

I believe this code makes clearer the actions described above, because details like the several assignments to `\next` can be avoided.

Here's a `\let\next` free version of the same macros

```
\newif\ifsilent
\def\specialhat{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter^%
  \else
    \expandafter\beginxref
  \fi
}
\def\beginxref{\futurelet\next\beginxrefswitch}
\def\beginxrefswitch{%
  \ifx\next\specialhat
    \expandafter\silentxref
  \else
    \silentfalse\expandafter\xref
  \fi
}
\catcode`\^=\active \let ^=\specialhat
\def\silentxref^{\silenttrue\xref}
```

Comment: The `\next` free version is not `\next` free ;) +1

Comment: @HenriMenke Well, you know what I mean; something after `\futurelet` is needed, I could have called it `\henrimenke`.

Answer (score 13):

If you are referring to the use of `^` like in `^^{TeX78}` and `^^|\copyright|`, here's the relevant part from manmac.tex

```
% Indexing macros
\newif\ifproofmode
\proofmodetrue % this should be false when making camera-ready copy
\newwrite\inx
\immediate\openout\inx=index % file for index reminders
\newif\ifsilent
\def\specialhat{\ifmmode\def\next{^}\else\let\next=\beginxref\fi\next}
\def\beginxref{\futurelet\next\beginxrefswitch}
\def\beginxrefswitch{\ifx\next\specialhat\let\next=\silentxref
  \else\silentfalse\let\next=\xref\fi \next}
\catcode`\^=\active \let ^=\specialhat
\def\silentxref^{\silenttrue\xref}
```

Basically it defines `\specialhat` and then does `\let^=\specialhat`. It's his way of doing a clean reference system to the index (he seemed to like `^^{foo}` notation I guess, rather than, say `\index{..}` or `\index|..|`).

Then he defines `\xref` which is the actual function. `^` is just the “public interface” to `\xref`.

```
\def\marginstyle{\vrule height6pt depth2pt width\z@ \sevenrm}

\chardef\bslash=`\\
\def\xref{\futurelet\next\xrefswitch}
\def\xrefswitch{\begingroup
  \ifx\next|\aftergroup\vxref % case 1 or 2, |arg| or |\arg|
  \else\ifx\next\<\aftergroup\anglexref % case 3, "\<arg>" means angle brackets
    \else\aftergroup\normalxref \fi\fi\endgroup} % case 0, "{arg}"
\def\vxref|{\catcode`\\=\active \futurelet\next\vxrefswitch}
\def\vxrefswitch#1|{\catcode`\\=0
  \ifx\next\empty\def\xreftype{2}%
    \def\next{{\tt\bslash\text}}% type 2, |\arg|
  \else\def\xreftype{1}\def\next{{\tt\text}}\fi % type 1, |arg|
  \edef\text{#1}\makexref}
{\catcode`\|=0 \catcode`\\=\active |gdef\{}}
\def\anglexref\<#1>{\def\xreftype{3}\def\text{#1}%
  \def\next{\<\text>}\makexref}
\def\normalxref#1{\def\xreftype{0}\def\text{#1}\let\next=\text\makexref}
\def\makexref{\ifproofmode\insert\margin{\hbox{\marginstyle\text}}%
   \xdef\writeit{\write\inx{\text\space!\xreftype\space
     \noexpand\number\pageno.}}\writeit
   \else\ifhmode\kern\z@\fi\fi
  \ifsilent\ignorespaces\else\next\fi}
% the \insert (which is done in proofmode only) suppresses hyphenation,
% so the \kern\z@ is put in to give the same effect in non-proofmode.
```

I'm not an expert, others might give better details and reasons for this.

Answer (score 10):

The `^` character is used either to indicate the switch to superscript typesetting or it is a character replacement method (better shifting method),e.g.

`^^+` will be replaced by the character `k`, since `k` and `+` differ by 64 positions in the ordinary ASCII code, it's possible to say

`\vs^^+ip 8cm` instead of `\vskip 8cm`

Identically, `^^k` will replaced by `+` then, but this hard to read, in my point of view.

The `^^` code is called character internal representation.

Here's a strange way of saying `Hello World` (compile with `TeX` or `pdfTeX`)

```
H^^%^^,^^,^^/  W^^/^^2^^,^^$
\^^"^^9^^%
```

Comment: For the `k` and `+` examples you gave each `^` is equal to a 32 position change? And can any character be used instead of a `+`?

Comment: @AFeldman Yes, with some caveats; `^^` *x* is replaced by ASCII *x* + 64 or *x* – 64, whichever is in the range 0–127 (here *x* stands for any printable ASCII character). But in case *x* is among `0123456789abcdef` the thing is slightly different: if the next character is in the same group, `^^` *xy* is replaced by the ASCII character obtained by interpreting *xy* as hexadecimal.

Comment: “When you look at the dark side, careful you must be. For the dark side looks back.” Yoda