# Insert Unicode private char

Tags: symbols, lists, unicode, characters

How I type the unicode char  in latex?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If the engine is Unicode aware and a font is used, which contains the glyph for the private Unicode code point:

```
^^^^e25f
```

See: [The ^^ notation in various engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62725/16967). This is TeX's method to encode non-ASCII characters with ASCII and can also be used inside command tokens.

There are also commands to select a character by slot in the current font:

LaTeX command:

```
\symbol{"E25F}
```

or the (plain) TeX variant:

```
\char"E25F\relax
```

BTW, there is a non-private code point for this glyph:

[U+27A2](http://unicode-table.com/en/27A2/) Three-D Top-Lighted Rightwards Arrowhead

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \begingroup\fontspec{#1}\symbol{"27A2}\endgroup
}
\test{DejaVu Sans}
\test{Segoe UI Symbol}
\end{document}
```

> [image: U+27A2]