# Exotic symbol in the argument of \section

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I need an exotic symbol in the title of a section (the class is *book*). So, I write `\section{Bla-bla \hbox{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}\char"36}  tititi}`. 
 It works perfectly well in the title, but in the *running title* the symbol just *disappears*, it is

> Bla-bla   tititi

What can be done?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this would be much easier to diagnose if you would provide a brief example that we could just cut and paste to experiment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the running title you need to stop `\MakeUpperCase` changing your symbol.  One way to this is to define a command for the symbol, which you can use anywhere, and in section titles proceed it by `\protect`.  A simpler solution is to define the command via `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mysymb}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}\symbol{"36}}}

\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\section{Bla-bla \mysymb{} tititi}

\end{document}
```

Defining the symbol this way allows it to change size with the surrounding text.  Note that I have changed `\char` to `\symbol{...}` as recommended by egreg.

Comment: Why not `\DeclareRobustCommand`, that avoids the need for `\protect`? I also recommend `\symbol{"36}` instead of `\char"36`.

Comment: The problem, in fact, is caused not by \MakeUpperCase (though I also thought so), However, \protect does work anyway. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ egreg Without protection the replacement \char"36 ->   \symbol{"36} doesn't work all the same. But \DeclareRobustCommand is a good idea. Thanks

Comment: @egreg Indeed that works and is simpler to use, so I have updated the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ Andrew Swann, Sorry for an additional question, but why is it important to change \char to \symbol{...}?

Comment: @Serguei `\char` works in this case, but `\char` is the TeX primitive command, `\symbol` is a LaTeX wrapper with the advantage that the argument is enclosed in `{...}` so clearly delimited.  The LaTeX kernel defines `\symbol{#1}` to be `{\char #1\relax}`.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305676/15925.