# How to paste a Mathematica formula to the latex(\unicode{} included)?

Tags: fonts, unicode, wolfram-mathematica

Recently, I'm learning how to use Mathematica, and I want to make some notes with LaTeX. I noticed that Mathematica have provide a function "TeXForm", but when dealing with this:

[image]

the output is `\text{Graph}[\{a\unicode{f3d5}b\}]`

I know what the `\unicode{}` command is, because when I use "ExportString" in the Mathematica, I got

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}
\[\text{Graph}[\{a\unicode{f3d5}b\}]\]
\end{document}
```

However, when I when I generated the pdf file, I got only

[image]

It is obvious that the symbol between `a` and `b` isn't displayed.

Then I looked up for the Unicode f3d5 in the font MathematicaMono (the font mathematica used to display symbols), I found the symbol I want, but how can I put this symbol (or character) into my pdf file, that is, how to apply this symbol to the latex environment `displaymath`.

By the way, I'm using WinEdt10.1, with MiKTeX and PDFTeXify (PDFLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX or others are also available).

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305676/8528), which can be adapted to suit your issue. But, basically, you need to redefine `\unicode` so it prints something (right now it does not); and it would be useful to use either `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile.

Comment: there are files with more or less standard mappings between unicode numbers and tex command names, eg uniocde-math-table.tex in the unicode-math package, however despite the name of the command mathematica is not using unicode here, or at least only superficially. U+F353 is not a defined unicode code point, it is part of the  "private use area" so you will need to define `\unicode{f3d5}` to make a suitable arrow.

Comment: @jon Much appreciated, your answer gave me inspiration. Now I can correctly insert certain symbols using `XeLaTeX` with package fontspec and the command `\symbol`. There is a small problem: I'd like to make it a new command using `\newcommand{\unicode}{\textnormal{\fontspec{MathematicaMono}\symbol{"#1}}}` or `\newcommand{\unicode}{\textnormal{\fontspec{MathematicaMono}^^^^#1}}`, but neither of them works. The first one can not recognize the lower case like `f3d5`. And the second one tries to convert `^^^^#1` to a Unicode char, causing compile error. If there is a solution can solve them?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Also thanks. Indeed, the Unicode f3d5 is in the "Private use area", however, I can find it out from the Mathematica font file --- MathematicaMono.ttf. Currently, the problem I'm facing becomes how should I (re)define `\unicode` to insert these symbols easily ,(two atempts are shown above), because the Mathematica can only generate code points in lowercases, that is, it can only generate `f3d5`, but not `F3D5`, which can be used by `\symbol` directly, and I can't find such a command to convert an parameter into its uppercase.

Comment: Instead of `\symbol{"#1}` try `\uppercase{\symbol{"#1}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all of you, @jon, @DavidCarlisle and @BrunoLeFloch. Without your help, I can't solve this problem on my own.

Here is a sample showing how should I do to solve it. With winedt10.1, XeLaTeX, and package `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %this line is added.
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{\textnormal{\fontspec{MathematicaMono}\uppercase{\symbol{"#1}}}} %this line is modified.
\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}
\[\text{Graph}[\{a\unicode{f3d5}b\}]\]
\end{document}
```

Except the line with comment, the other lines are directly generated by Mathematica.

And that is the key:

```
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{\textnormal{\fontspec{MathematicaMono}\uppercase{\symbol{"#1}}}}
```

Of course, you need to install the font MathematicaMono first, then you can import your formula directly from the Mathematica without any modification.

---

A better version of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\mathematicamono}{MathematicaMono}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mmono}{m}
 {
  \text{\mathematicamono#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\unicode}{m}
 {
  \mmono { \symbol { \int_from_hex:n { #1 } } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\text{Graph}[\{a\unicode{f3d5}b\}]\]

\[\text{Graph}[\{a\mathrel{\unicode{f3d5}}b\}]\]

\end{document}
```

[image]