# New command definition causes "Missing number, treated as zero" error

Tags: macros, xetex, xepersian

I am writing something in Persian language, and I want to manage the space between some words. 
I defined:

```
\newcommand{\nf}{\char\value{226}\char\value{128}\char\value{140}}
```

But after building the document, I see "! Missing number, treated as zero" error at each line I've used \nf ...

Here is a short example file:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\newcommand{\nf}{\char\value{226}\char\value{128}\char\value{140}}

\begin{document}
اگر $n$ نقطهٔ رنگی در صفحه از $k$ رنگ مختلف داشته باشیم، می\nf
خواهیم یک شکل هندسی (دایره، مثلث و ...) را طوری در صفحه قرار دهیم که از هر رنگ دست\nf
کم یکی پوشانده شود.
\end{document}
```

I am using TeXMaker 4.4.1 on Ubuntu 1604; What's wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `\value` refers to the value of a counter. I doubt that there are counters with *names* `226`, `128`, and `140`. I assume you meant the numbers:

```
\char226 \char128 \char140
```

In LaTeX provides the macro `\symbol` (that takes care of the proper ending of the number):

```
\newcommand*{\nf}{\symbol{226}\symbol{128}\symbol{140}}
```

But the numbers raise the suspicion that this is meant as a Unicode character encoded as UTF-8. This is a *different* story.

With 8-bit TeX engines this can be written as:

```
\newcommand*{\nf}{^^e2^^80^^8c}
```

But with Unicode-aware TeX engines (XeTeX, LuaTeX), the character can be specified directly. Or with the ^-notation ([The ^^ notation in various engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62725/16967)):

```
\newcommand*{\nf}{^^^^200c}
```

The symbol is: U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER

Comment: It was not work in this way too! I have question marks at each \nf, in output pdf :(