# Can't use 5-digit hexadecimal numbers with ^^^^^

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I'm getting this exact error message (including linebreaks)

```
! ^^^^ needs four hex digits.
l.5 \newcommand{\boldpsi}{^
                          ^^^^1d6d9}
```

for this piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\newcommand{\boldpsi}{^^^^^1d6d9}
\begin{document}
$\boldpsi$
\end{document}
```

I checked [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62725/the-notation-in-various-engines) but 5 carets seem the way to go.

Comment: you need either four or six `^`, so use `^^^^^^01d6d9`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am 100% certain I tried that already but it didnt'work (with the extra 0 as well). But now it does...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Five carets work with XeTeX, but not with LuaTeX, which only accepts two, four or six.

Unfortunately, the answer still had the five caret notation. (Edited, now.)

Comment: In fact, the answer is about an older version of LuaTeX that still accepted five carets with five hex digits. It is only in the comments where you find that since LuaTeX 0.85 five carets are no longer supported.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica I read it and I overlooked the five carets part. Now I edited both answers